# In Pine, how to retrieve strategy.netprofit resulting of different parameter values?

Tags: pine-script

I would like to display the netprofit of a strategy over different scenarios, i.e, over different conditions on the exit order:

```
//@version=5
strategy("test 2", overlay=true, max_labels_count=500, calc_on_every_tick=true, initial_capital=500, default_qty_value = 500, currency='USD', process_orders_on_close=true, commission_type='percent', commission_value=0.075, default_qty_type=strategy.cash, calc_on_order_fills=true)


// retrieve Heikin Ashi values
haHandle=ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid)
haOpen=request.security(haHandle,timeframe.period,open)
haClose=request.security(haHandle,timeframe.period,close)
haDeltaAbs=haClose-haClose[1]
haDeltaRel=haDeltaAbs/haClose[1]*100


// Trade Entry
haEntryCondition=haDeltaRel>0 and haDeltaRel[1]<0
strategy.entry("trade", strategy.long, when = haEntryCondition)


// Trade Exit, I perform one Exit order for three different values of a thresold condition (-1, -0.5, 0)
float haThreshold = -1
for i = 0 to 2
    haThreshold := haThreshold + 0.5
    haExitCondition=haDeltaRel<haThreshold
    strategy.close("trade"+str.tostring(i), when = haExitCondition)
    
// I would like to display the result of the strategy (strategy.netprofit) for each of the "type" of exit performed above
if (barstate.islast)
    label.new(bar_index, open, str.tostring(strategy.netprofit), yloc = yloc.price, style = label.style_none, textcolor = color.red, size = size.normal)
```

The last line (label.new(... ) only displays the total net profit (all entries/exits taken into account). Instead, how can I retrieve the net profit that corresponds to each of the "configurations" on the exit order ?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by each type? There is only one `strategy.close` in your code. Do you want to calculate the net profit of each trade separately?

Comment: Yes there is only one strategy.close indeed, and I have the intuition that I could use different IDs (like "trade01", "trade02") corresponding to the different configurations

Comment: I want to calculate the netprofit for each "configuration" i.e for each parameter value association. I.e if I have two variables/parameters x1 and x2, with respectively 0.1/0.2 and 23/25 values, THEN I want to know, separatly, the netprofit of : (x1=0.1 and x2=23) OF (x1=0.1 and x2=25) OF (x1=0.2 and x2=23) AND (OF x1=0.2 and x2=25)

Comment: I updated my post and associated each close trade with a different ID (corresponding to a different configuration of parameters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this running a loop checking for the entry id and adding up the profit by name.

```
profitByName(name) =>
    result = 0.
    for i = 0 to strategy.closedtrades-1
        if strategy.closedtrades.entry_id(i) == name
            result += strategy.closedtrades.profit(i) 
    result
```

You could also look for the exit id:

```
profitByExitName(name) =>
    result = 0.
    for i = 0 to strategy.closedtrades-1
        if strategy.closedtrades.exit_id(i) == name
            result += strategy.closedtrades.profit(i) 
    result
```

There are many other handy built-ins in this name space that are worth looking in to